# C# Entity Update Table Failing

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, composite-primary-key

I've a table that has composite primary key as provided below. I'm trying to add/update/delete functionality using C# MVC. Add and Delete works fine but Update for EffectiveDate Column is failing as there are multiple rows with same ClientName and Portfolio exists. Table Stucture and Entity/Service code is provided below. Can you please take a look what I'm missing in code?

**RunTime Error:**

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomAUM](
[Client] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
[Portfolio] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[AUM] [numeric](30, 6) NOT NULL,
[EffectiveDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[IsStatic] [char](1) NULL,
[sysDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ModifiedBy] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomAUM] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Portfolio] ASC,
    [Client] ASC,
    [EffectiveDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Entity Code**

```
public class Custom
{

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual string Client { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public virtual string Portfolio { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual decimal AUM { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string IsStatic { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime sysDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public virtual string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

}

public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Custom>
{
    public CustomerAUMMap()
    {
        //Primary Key
        this.HasKey(k => new { k.Client, k.Portfolio, k.EffectiveDate });

        this.ToTable("CustomAUM");

        this.Property(x => x.Client).HasColumnName("Client");
        this.Property(x => x.Portfolio).HasColumnName("Portfolio");
        this.Property(x => x.AUM).HasColumnName("AUM");
        this.Property(x => x.EffectiveDate).HasColumnName("EffectiveDate");
        this.Property(x => x.IsStatic).HasColumnName("IsStatic");
        this.Property(x => x.sysDate).HasColumnName("sysDate");
        this.Property(x => x.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy");
    }
}
```

**Service Method**

```
public void CustomAUM_Update(RiskReportDataViewModel riskReportDataViewModel, string userName)
    {
            var entity = new Custom();

            entity.Client = riskReportDataViewModel.Client;
            entity.Portfolio = riskReportDataViewModel.Portfolio;
            entity.AUM = riskReportDataViewModel.AUM;
            entity.EffectiveDate = DateTime.Parse(riskReportDataViewModel.EffectiveDate.ToShortDateString());
            entity.IsStatic = riskReportDataViewModel.IsStatic;
            entity.sysDate = DateTime.Now;
            entity.ModifiedBy = userName;

            riskContext.Custom.Attach(entity);
            riskContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            riskContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

// View Model

```
public class RiskReportDataViewModel
{

    [Key]
    public virtual string Client { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public virtual string Portfolio { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal AUM { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public virtual DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

    public virtual String IsStatic { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime sysDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public virtual string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: I've updated with RunTime Error I'm getting. I think it means not able to save any Row in DB. - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem is to add a new Row as ID and make a composite primary key. Thanks to Jun An for sharing ideas. Modified code looks like this -

**DB Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomAUM](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Client] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [Portfolio] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [AUM] [numeric](30, 6) NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsStatic] [char](1) NULL,
    [sysDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomAUM_New] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [Portfolio] ASC,
    [Client] ASC,
    [EffectiveDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

> **Service Code**

```
public void CustomAUM_Update(RiskReportDataViewModel riskReportDataViewModel, string userName)
        {
                var entity = new CustomAUM();

                entity = riskContext.CustomAUM.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == riskReportDataViewModel.ID && x.Client == riskReportDataViewModel.Client && x.Portfolio == riskReportDataViewModel.Portfolio);

                entity.Client = riskReportDataViewModel.Client;
                entity.Portfolio = riskReportDataViewModel.Portfolio;
                entity.AUM = riskReportDataViewModel.AUM;
                entity.EffectiveDate = DateTime.Parse(riskReportDataViewModel.EffectiveDate.ToShortDateString());
                entity.IsStatic = riskReportDataViewModel.IsStatic;
                entity.sysDate = DateTime.Now;
                entity.ModifiedBy = userName;

                riskContext.CustomAUM.Attach(entity);
                riskContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                riskContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you updated with RiskReportDataViewModel, did you use Custom to update ?
show me the method for updating.

actually, you need to select to get "Custom" from database first, then change values of "Custom" and save.

and why you have three keys in custom model as below ?

```
public class Custom
{

[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]
public virtual string Client { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 2)]
public virtual string Portfolio { get; set; }

[Required]
public virtual decimal AUM { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 3)]
public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

[StringLength(50)]
[Column(TypeName = "char")]
public string IsStatic { get; set; }

[Required]
public DateTime sysDate { get; set; }

[StringLength(500)]
public virtual string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

}
```

add one of integer value for key.

Comment: I've provided CustomAUM_Update method code. Also I tried removing two keys. I think the table has composite primary key so I thought to use three keys. When I remove two keys this is the error I get. Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CustomAUM'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CustomAUM'. The duplicate key value is (L/S_BMAT (STEVENS), Verition, Jan  2 2017 12:00AM).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Service code is provided with updated code of CustomAUM_Update method. - Thanks.

Comment: Oh now i can see it, which ef version do you use ?

Comment: For me, i use ef core. So it looks little bit different. But first select Custom row using keys and change values then, saveChanges();  this is logic how to update

Comment: var custom = riskContext.Custom.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.key == key); something like that ... but your code just make new class of custom.. it should get model from context

Comment: I get it, this code is not working as there are multiple records with same Client and Portfolio. I also need to add Effective Date in Clause but issue is that the effective date I'm getting from UI is already modified one. I'm not able to get the exact row that I'm modifying in Kendo Grid. entity = riskContext.CustomAUM.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Client == riskReportDataViewModel.Client && x.Portfolio == riskReportDataViewModel.Portfolio);

Comment: You can use Where method instead of FirstOrDefault. Then, change values and save it

Comment: Problem is not with Where or FirstOrDefault. Issue is with Third Parameter in Where Clause. How can I get the modified row where effective date itself is changed ?

Comment: You mean do you need to change effective date ? You set effective date as one of the primary keys. Im not sure what I understood in wrong way, it does not make sense.. i recommend to add column of integer as index number then you can get custom model by index column then, you can modify effective date as well

Comment: Hey Jun, I think your idea worked. I added a id column and able to pull information with composite primary key and update exact row required. Thank you.